# TabLayout icon is hiding when swipe the other tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout with ViewPager. And I know, ViewPager override tab icons. So I'm giving their icons with Java code. But when I swipe the other page, the tabs icon is hiding or going somewhere. Do you guys have an idea to solve this issue?

So there is the images:

[image: Position 0]

[image: Position 1]

Here is my code:

**CreateGame.java**

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager= (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,true);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_loc_white);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_court_black); //viewPager ikonları eziyor. İkonları tekrar ver.
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.courtList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    courtInfoAdapter = new CourtInfoAdapter(getContext(), CreateGame.this,courtInfos);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());



    btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            if(tab.getPosition()==0)
            {
                int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lnr_main_height);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                deleteCourtInfos();
                upLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cardViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,1);
                params.setMargins(0,0,0,287);
                params.height=height;
                mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            if(tab.getPosition()==1)
            {

                int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lnr_main_height_change);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(courtInfoAdapter);
                fetchCourtInfos();
                upLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cardViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mainLayout.getLayoutParams());
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,0);
                params.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,1);
                params.height=height;
                mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            }
        }
```

**creategame.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_for_tab">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_loc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_loc_white" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_area"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_court_black" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem with using selector.

**For tab 0:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loc_white" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_location_with_border"/> <!-- default -->
```

**For tab 1:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_court_white" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_court_black"/> <!-- default -->
```